# Class template function signature syntax

Tags: c++

I have a class defined like this:

```
template< class TBoundingBox >
class BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator
{
  typedef PlaneSpatialObject< TBoundingBox::PointDimension > PlaneSpatialObjectType;
  typedef typename PlaneSpatialObjectType::Pointer      PlaneSpatialObjectPointer;
  std::vector<PlaneSpatialObjectPointer> GetPlanes() const{}
}
```

If I call the function like:

```
std::vector<PlaneCalculatorType::PlaneSpatialObjectPointer> planes = planeCalculator->GetPlanes();
```

It works fine. However, if I change the delcaration to simply

```
  std::vector<PlaneSpatialObjectPointer> GetPlanes() const;
```

and then try to define the function outside of the header:

```
template< class TBoundingBox >
std::vector<BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator< TBoundingBox >::PlaneSpatialObjectPointer>
BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator< TBoundingBox >::GetPlanes() const
{

}
```

I get

```
itkBoundingBoxPlaneCalculator.txx:61:82: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
itkBoundingBoxPlaneCalculator.txx:61:82: error:   expected a type, got ‘itk::BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator<TBoundingBox>::PlaneSpatialObjectPointer’
```

I also tried adding typename, but nothing changed:

```
template< class TBoundingBox >
std::vector<typename BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator< TBoundingBox >::PlaneSpatialObjectPointer>
BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator< TBoundingBox >::GetPlanes() const
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this syntax?

Thanks,

David

Comment: It's a good idea when posting here to reduce the issue to the minimum - particularly don't use very long names, good though they may be in your actual application code.

Comment: What is `TBoundingBox::PointDimension` ? A type? An integer? If it's a type, I keep wondering why you don't need a `typename` before that... And what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I just had to add typename in the calling function:

```
std::vector<typename PlaneCalculatorType::PlaneSpatialObjectPointer> planes = planeCalculator->GetPlanes();
```

I'm confused why it worked without it when the function was defined inside the class??

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much copy-pasted your code but used int to replace a type you didn't define, and this works fine for me (using g++ 4.4):

```
#include <vector>

template<class TBoundingBox>
class BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator
{
public:
    typedef int* PlaneSpatialObjectPointer;
    std::vector<PlaneSpatialObjectPointer> GetPlanes() const;
};

template<class TBoundingBox>
std::vector<typename BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator<TBoundingBox>::PlaneSpatialObjectPointer>
    BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator<TBoundingBox>::GetPlanes() const {}

int main()
{
    BoundingBoxPlaneCalculator<int> planeCalculator;
    planeCalculator.GetPlanes();
}
```

The thing is, this doesn't look really different from what you posted, except for the fact that `PlaneSpatialObjectPointer` wasn't declared in your code.  So either there's a typo or missing piece somewhere in your real code, or something else is afoot.

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.6. I'm trying to reduce the issue to a standalone, compilable example.

Comment: I wonder if throwing a `typename` in front of that might help then?  I don't know, I'm not super-familiar with MSVC and particularly not with this purported bug (got a link?).

Comment: Forget my comment, OP isn't using MSVC and even MSVC (2010 atleast) chokes when `PointDimension` is a type.

Comment: I tried to simplify the problem so it would stand alone. I don't know if I got it exactly right, but the new errors are: template argument 1 is invalid on the std::vector<> line in main()

Comment: Whose main(), yours or mine?  Does my code work for you or not?  If not, please paste the complete compiler error.